# install guzzle in laravel 5.4

Tags: installation, guzzle

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.0-rc.1, 4.0.0-rc.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.0-rc.1, 4.0.0-rc.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.0-rc.1, 4.0.0-rc.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for laravel/socialite 2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v2.0.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
"laravel/socialite": "2.0",

Comment: try `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` before installing this package, you should use laravel tag for us to help you faster

Comment: this error occurred when I try this,  composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle                           I have socialite package in composer.jason>> "laravel/socialite": "2.0",                             could you help me?

Comment: just added in the answer, edit your composer.json as below, & add guzzle before socialite

Comment: also NOTE: to remove any old guzzle installed before then using compose update

Answer (score 0):

I use bellow code in composer.json and it works.

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^4.2.4",`

then `comoser update`